# Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 - how to connect device wirelessly to computer?

Tags: samsung

I should first explain that the Tab connects wirelessly to my modem\router, and thence to the internet.
Also, it connects to the computer via USB cable.
However, I cannot get it to connect wirelessly to my computer, or any other of the five desktops and laptops that make up my home network.
I must be missing something basic.
Anyone have a suggestion?

BTW: All the PCs but one are W7 Ultimate 64bit. The other is W10 Enterprise.
All are connected via gigabit hub and are fully shared with each other.
Galaxy model is SM-T800. Android is 6.0.1.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What type of connection have you tried (what app on Android side and what settings/program on Windows)?

Comment: Thanks Robert. See my comment below to Oboe Wan Kenobe.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use a local WiFi connection to transfer the data. It has no way of knowing you want it to. There has to be a third party of some sort telling them both to talk.

I would recommend checking out apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&hl=en_US).

Or, for Android to Android, [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.share&hl=en_US).

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't aware that additional software was required for wifi file transfers.